# Using linq to intersect 2 arrays

Tags: linq, join

I believe I have to use a JOIN but I cant figure out how to utilize it properly using Linq

I have two arrays,

Array1 = array of  all Members (allMembers)

each member is an object that has a memberID as a string field

Array2 = array of MemberID strings (membersToSelect)

I want to return all the members whos memberID is listed int Array2.

This is what Ive tried so far

```
MemberObject[] selectedObjects = allMembers
                                           .Join( membersToSelect, 
                                           memberID => memberID, 
                                           member => member, 
                                           (memberID, member) => memberID == member.memberID)
                                          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you don't understand the LINQ join syntax. This particular overload allows you to specify which properties/objects will be used in the comparison (actually, uses hashing of the keys you specify to create a Lookup).

The main concept is that it is very similar to a SQL join, in that you are deciding your join columns (the second and third parameters).

```
allMembers // The original collection
    .Join(membersToSelect, // The collection to join
        allMem => allMem.MemberID, // Selects your original collections join column
        joinMem => joinMem, // Selects your joining collections join column (or element)
        (allMem, joinMem) => allMem) // This "combines" matching elements into the new element you specify.
        .ToArray();
```

In this particular example of yours, the final transformation (for joined elements) results in the outcome being an array of boolean values, which doesn't really help much in this case. That final parameter is ultimately the matches that you get for the original/joined collection. In other words, `(allMem, joinMem) =>` above is the matching `Member`/`string` in your join.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, that helped me understand JOIN a lot better!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this:

```
var selectedObjects = allMembers
    .Where(x => membersToSelect.Contains(x.memberID))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Ive done it this way using a single parameter to match against, so your saying that it will also match against everything in the membersToSelect Array?

Comment: Erm, not sure what you mean?